# DC-coupled wide-bandwidth differential to single-ended conversion

Tags: differential, single-ended

I'm designing a circuit that produces differential signal outputs in the frequency range from DC to about 2 GHz. This differential signal will be driven by an FDA (probably LMH6401 or LMH5401). I'd like to be able to use these differential outputs directly. However, I'd also like the option to convert this to a single-ended signal and use that instead. The differential outputs would each drive 50 ohm coax. The single-ended output would reuse one of the existing differential connectors.

What are my options for this differential to single-ended conversion?

It seems like there are, in general, several options for differential to single-ended conversion:

1. balun with one output side grounded
2. op-amp: differential input to single-ended output
3. terminate one output into a load equal to the characteristic impedance of the line (50 ohms in this case)

Option (1) is out because this cannot pass DC.

2 GHz is AFAIK outside the frequency of non-FDA op-amps, so that rules out option (2) as well.

Option (3) has the downside of losing half the output signal (assuming I don't make any adjustments to the driving FDA gain). But that's an acceptable cost to me and seems to be the only significant downside.

The other benefit to option (3) is that it doesn't require switching between two signal paths.

Are there any other downsides to simply terminating one output? Anything I should watch out for? Any other options that might work well here?

---

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/110311/190755) recommends option (3) and probably provides a reasonable answer to this question. However, this question is a bit more specific in the sense that it asks for alternatives and downsides to this approach, so I believe it's still worth asking.

Comment: There are op-amps with up to 8 GHz (at least, I just looked at TI.com) GBW. Whether they can also drive the amplitude you need I don't know. Are you working with digital signals? Do you really need down to DC or is your data encoded to eliminate DC content?

Comment: I should have mentioned: this is for analog signals and is sensitive to noise and gain flatness. I took a quick look at some of those options and many (all?) have minimum gain settings greater than 1, which limits the usable bandwidth for me. I don't really need gain here, just bandwidth. Signal levels are up to about 3Vpp differential (though I'd be ok with a bit less). It does need to support DC. Actual DC operation would probably be rare (but valid). But, very low frequency signals (mHz, possibly even uHz) are definitely possible.